# Как подключить плату к uart на esp-01

Tags: c++, esp8266, rs232, uart, arduino-uno

я пытаюсь подключить зеленую плату к ESP-01 WIFI модуль через Arduino через выходы out+ out- (выделено красным) к входам RX вход и TX выход, если подключить оба выхода какие то циферки идут после преобразования в int, но я думаю это не правильное подключение, может по схеме кто то поймет что это за выходы и как или через что подключать? Зеленая плата отправляет количество импульсов от расходомера жидкости для подсчета скорости потока и объема пройденной жидкости. Фото схемы и платы прилагается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы сайтом немного ошиблись....  cxem.net и тд - вам туда

Comment: и туда уже обратился

Comment: У нас в сети есть специальный сайт для ардуинщиков, но он на английском. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/